# elastic serach find documents based on location

Tags: php, elasticsearch, couchbase

I am using elastic search 1.4 with couchbase 3.2. I have to find all the documents based on the location. As for example i have to find the user latitude and longitude and display all the events nearby him for which his interests matched. I am storing event data on couchbase as.

```
{
  "createdUnder": "11",
  "createdby": "4",
  "name": "Vcunnect April Event Testing",
  "location": "Madurai, Tamil Nadu, India",
  "address": {
      "venuename": "MKU University",
      "address1": "MKU University",
      "address2": "MKU University",
      "city": "Madurai",
      "state": "Tamil Nadu",
      "country": "India",
      "zipcode": "875485"
  },
  "description": "Vcunnect testing Event\r\n",
  "lat": "9.9252007",
  "lng": "78.11977539999998",
  "startdate": "08/10/2016",
  "enddate": "08/10/2016",
  "starttime": "5:20pm",
  "endtime": "7:00pm",
  "organisers": [
     {
         "organisername": "Raushan Kumar",
         "organiseremail": "raushankumar@gmail.in",
         "organiserdescription": "Event Organizer",
         "status": "active"
     }
  ],
  "starttimestamp": 1470867600,
  "endtimestamp": 1470873600
}
```

I have two fields as "lat" and "lng" in my document. using this and user location latitude and longitude i want to find the events nearby the user. I am using this query for getting the documents.

```
    $searchParams['index'] = 'events';
    $searchParams['type'] = 'couchbaseDocument';
    $searchParams['from'] = 0;
    $searchParams['size'] = 1000;
    $searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]['term']['displaystatus'] = 0;
    $searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]['term']['eventstatus'] = "active";
    $searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]['range']['starttimestamp']['from'] = $today;
    $searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]['term']['displayoutside'] = 1;
    $searchParams['body']['query']['filtered']['filter']['bool']['must'][]['terms']['cat_id'] = $interestIdArray;
    $result = $client->search($searchParams);
```

My mapping in the json file is as

```
{
"template" : "*",
"order" : 10,
"mappings" : {
    "couchbaseCheckpoint" : {
        "_source" : {
            "includes" : ["doc.*"]
        },
        "dynamic_templates": [
            {
                "store_no_index": {
                    "match": "*",
                    "mapping": {
                        "store" : "no",
                        "index" : "no",
                        "include_in_all" : false
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_default_" : {
        "_source" : {
            "includes" : ["meta.*"]
        },
        "properties" : {
            "meta" : {
                "type" : "object",
                "include_in_all" : false
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I have five indices at my elasticsearch cluster named "events,groups,chatmessages,sponsors and userdata". From them i want to location based mapping for only events and groups indices. What i have to changed..?

Comment: hey @val, any suggestion from your side

Comment: How does your ES mapping look like?

Comment: in my mapping it is displayed as
"mappings":{
     "couchbaseDocument":{
          "doc":{
                  "lan":{
                       "type":"string"
                   },
                  "lat":{
                       "type":"string"
                  }
           }
      }
}

Comment: hey @Val, I research and found that this is the default mapping for elasticsearch couchbase_template.json. May you provide me a sample of mapping structure for an index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: this answer is specific to ES 1.x, the syntax will be somewhat different in 2.x*

If you want to store coordinates in a way that will be queryable in Elasticsearch, you have to do the following:

1. Store the lat/lon in a format that ES will be able to map to a geo_point, which means either as sub-properties of an object `{ 'location': {'lat': 123, 'lon': 123}}`, or as an array `[<lon>, <lat>]`  (note the order here).
2. Manually update the ES mapping to treat your location field as a geo_point type. Take a look here for an example: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-geo-point-type.html
3. Use one of the geo filters to query by distance/range/bounding shape, e.g. geo_distance filter: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/query-dsl-geo-distance-filter.html

Example:

Document mapping fragment to index the location as a geo_point type:

```
{
    "data" : {
        "properties" : {
            "location" : {
                "type" : "geo_point"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Document with a location:

```
{
    "data" : {
        "location" : {
            "lat" : 9.9252007,
            "lon" : 78.11977539999998
        }
    }
}
```

Query to find documents with a location within a 10km radius of some point (should return at least the preceeding example doc):

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "query" : {
            "match_all" : {}
        },
        "filter" : {
            "geo_distance" : {
                "distance" : "10km",
                "data.location" : {
                    "lat" : 9.9,
                    "lon" : 78.12
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where i can manually update the ES mapping. This is an existing project and i have no much idea about how mapping is created and how i can update it. Will you explain me the process.

Comment: hey @David i am using **elasticsearch-couchbase-transport-2.1.1** for using Couchbase Server with Elasticsearch

Comment: You might want to take a look at this blog, it explains how to update mappings on existing indexes: https://www.elastic.co/blog/changing-mapping-with-zero-downtime

Comment: Alternatively, you should update the template that comes with the Couchbase-ES plugin (it's a json file located in the plugin install directory) to include your custom mappings, update (HTTP PUT) the template in ES and then create a new index, which will then use the updated mappings from the template. Go here for more information about templates: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/indices-templates.html

Comment: thanks @ David Ostrovsky, I edit my question and added my mappings, i have to change the mapping for only two indices, what i have to modify there, other all fields may be remain same

Comment: I research and found that this is the default mapping for elasticsearch couchbase_template.json. May you provide me a sample of mapping structure for an index